# Selected date from $cordovaDatePicker not being captured (ngCordova plugin)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have the following code snippet in my application:

```
 ...
 $scope.fn.showDatePicker = function () {
            $cordovaDatePicker.show({
                    date: new Date(),
                    mode: 'date'
                },
                function (date) {
                    $scope.display.completionDate = $filter('date')(new Date(date));
                }
            );
        };
...
```

And the following HTML:

```
...
<input type="text" ng-model="displaycompletionDate" placeholder="Est. Completion Date" />
<button class="button button-dark button-small center-button" ng-click="fn.showDatePicker()">Click</button>
...
```

The native datepicker comes up fine but after I select the date, it doesn't seem to run the callback function. (or at least, my $scope variable is does not seem to be populated) I have only tested this on Android so far. The version of cordova I am using is 3.5.0-0.2.7. I am injecting the $cordovaDatePicker and get no errors.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging around and discovered the documentation on [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#DatePicker) is outdated. According to this [commit log](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/commit/34c95660e324c744a30ce7cd0924a98baf8a671c), we now get the entered date via a promise instead of a callback:

```
$cordovaDatePicker.show({
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date'
}).then(function (date) {
    $scope.display.completionDate = $filter('date')(new Date(date));
});
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there who was looking at ngCordova documentation.